# GDAL Creating color ramp gives "ERROR 1: TIFFSetField:Images/out.tif: Cannot modify tag "PhotometricInterpretation" while writing"

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, colormap

I am receiving a weird error when creating my color ramp using GDAL color options. Here is a working version of my code

```
import numpy as np
import os
from osgeo import osr, gdal

#Load in and format numpy array
data_array = np.load('concentrations.npy') 
data_array = data_array[::-1]
data_array_scaled = np.interp(data_array, (data_array.min(), data_array.max()), (0, 255))
avg = np.float64(data_array_scaled[0,0])
data_array_scaled[data_array_scaled == avg] = 0 #Give no-data pixels value 0

r = data_array_scaled

RES    = 0.025
WIDTH  = data_array_scaled.shape[1]
HEIGHT = data_array_scaled.shape[0]

output_file = "Images/out.tif"

# Create GeoTIFF
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

# Upper Left x, East-West px resolution, rotation, Upper Left y, rotation, North-South px resolution
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform( [ -180, RES, 0, 90, 0, -RES ] )

# Set CRS
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84")
dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )

# Write the band
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(0) #optional if no-data transparent
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(r)

# Set colour map
band = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1) 
colors = gdal.ColorTable()

# Splits color ramp into 16 different colours (equal-interval)
colors.CreateColorRamp(  1, (253, 227,  30),  16, (212, 226,  27))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 16, (212, 226,  27),  32, (171, 219,  25))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 32, (171, 219,  25),  48, (133, 215,  46))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 48, (133, 215,  46),  64, ( 75, 189,  85))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 64, ( 75, 189,  85),  80, ( 61, 173, 101))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 80, ( 61, 173, 101),  96, ( 31, 168, 109))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 96, ( 31, 168, 109), 112, ( 30, 147, 112))
colors.CreateColorRamp(112, ( 30, 147, 112), 128, ( 28, 123, 125))
colors.CreateColorRamp(128, ( 28, 123, 125), 144, ( 39, 102, 124))
colors.CreateColorRamp(144, ( 39, 102, 124), 160, ( 34,  91, 117))
colors.CreateColorRamp(160, ( 34,  91, 117), 176, ( 46,  79, 121))
colors.CreateColorRamp(176, ( 46,  79, 121), 192, ( 45,  54, 114))
colors.CreateColorRamp(192, ( 45,  54, 114), 208, ( 54,  36, 110))
colors.CreateColorRamp(208, ( 54,  36, 110), 224, ( 54,  25, 100))
colors.CreateColorRamp(224, ( 54,  25, 100), 240, ( 51,   9,  86))
colors.CreateColorRamp(240, ( 51,   9,  86), 255, ( 52,   0,  67))

band.SetRasterColorTable(colors) # Using debugger, I found this is where the Error occurs
band.SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_PaletteIndex)
del band, dst_ds
```

The code still runs (error isn't fatal) but the resulting tiff is in greyscale. When using a numpy array filled with random values, this error doesn't occur and the resulting tiff is colored according to my colormap. Is there something in my data which could be causing this?

Data Info:

- `dtype = 'float32'`
- `shape = (7200, 14400)`
- `max = 2.8664365e-06`
- `min = 1.2119261e-06`
- `mean = 2.2154409e-06`

Unfortunately I cannot share the actual data file. Any insight? It was working with another numpy array and it works with a randomly generated one but I can't figure out what broke the color ramp from this array.

Comment: "While writing" suggests that writing is not finalized when SetRasterColorInterpretation tries to edit the tiff tag. Have you tried to wait for a moment?

Comment: Is the data info you are giving the one of your original raster or the rescaled raster? Would not make sense to apply that colormap to a raster with those `min` and `max` values.

Comment: Also, what happens if you set the color table before writing the array or create a band variable once instead of calling `ds.GetRasterBand(1)` multiple times?

Comment: @MarceloVilla I am giving it the rescaled raster (min 1, max 255, nodata 0). You're right about making a band variable, I changed so I only call that once. That alone didn't fix it. Setting color table before writing the array seems to have done it! Any explanation for this? Specifically why it wasn't an issue with my other array?

Comment: I am not sure why this would happen with this array and not with the other one. I would suggest creating a new question, providing two minimal reproducible examples. Also, I will add my previous comment as an answer so future readers can benefit from it and this question does'nt appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the color table before writing the array:

```py
# create color table and split color ramp into 16 different colours (equal-interval)
colors = gdal.ColorTable()
colors.CreateColorRamp(  1, (253, 227,  30),  16, (212, 226,  27))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 16, (212, 226,  27),  32, (171, 219,  25))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 32, (171, 219,  25),  48, (133, 215,  46))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 48, (133, 215,  46),  64, ( 75, 189,  85))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 64, ( 75, 189,  85),  80, ( 61, 173, 101))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 80, ( 61, 173, 101),  96, ( 31, 168, 109))
colors.CreateColorRamp( 96, ( 31, 168, 109), 112, ( 30, 147, 112))
colors.CreateColorRamp(112, ( 30, 147, 112), 128, ( 28, 123, 125))
colors.CreateColorRamp(128, ( 28, 123, 125), 144, ( 39, 102, 124))
colors.CreateColorRamp(144, ( 39, 102, 124), 160, ( 34,  91, 117))
colors.CreateColorRamp(160, ( 34,  91, 117), 176, ( 46,  79, 121))
colors.CreateColorRamp(176, ( 46,  79, 121), 192, ( 45,  54, 114))
colors.CreateColorRamp(192, ( 45,  54, 114), 208, ( 54,  36, 110))
colors.CreateColorRamp(208, ( 54,  36, 110), 224, ( 54,  25, 100))
colors.CreateColorRamp(224, ( 54,  25, 100), 240, ( 51,   9,  86))
colors.CreateColorRamp(240, ( 51,   9,  86), 255, ( 52,   0,  67))

# get raster band
band = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# set color table
band.SetRasterColorTable(colors)
band.SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_PaletteIndex)

# set NoData value and write array
band.SetNoDataValue(0) #optional if no-data transparent
band.WriteArray(r)

# close and save
band = None
dst_ds = None
```